# Elasticsearch has_child query with term and function_score, parsing_exception

Tags: elasticsearch

Sending post request to elastic search following is the post data

```
{
    "query": {
            "has_child" : {
                "type" : "sometype",
                "score_mode" : "sum",
                "query" : {
                    "term" : {
                        "somefield" : "somevalue"
                    },
                    "function_score" : {
                        "script_score": {"script": "1"}
                    }
                },
                "inner_hits": {}
            }
        }
      }
    }
```

Getting response as malformed query

```
{
"error": {
    "root_cause": [
        {
            "type": "parsing_exception",
            "reason": "[term] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]",
            "line": 10,
            "col": 17
        }
    ],
    "type": "parsing_exception",
    "reason": "[term] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]",
    "line": 10,
    "col": 17
},
"status": 400
```

}

Read documentation from this link: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.4/query-dsl-has-child-query.html

Elasticsearch version: 5.4

Comment: What happens if you remove the `function_score` query?

Comment: Its gives proper response

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure to wrap your `term` and `function_score` queries in a  `bool/filter` query, like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "has_child": {
      "type": "sometype",
      "score_mode": "sum",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "somefield": "somevalue"
              }
            },
            {
              "function_score": {
                "script_score": {
                  "script": "1"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "inner_hits": {}
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I am getting results, but _score of every hit is 0

Comment: {
 "hits": {
  "max_score": 0,
  "hits": [{
   "_index": "someindex",
   "_type": "parent",
   "_id": "1343",
   "_score": 0,
   "inner_hits": {
    "child": {
     "hits": {
      "total": 2,
      "max_score": 0,
      "hits": [{
        "_type": "child",
        "_id": "some_id_1",
        "_score": 0,
       },
       {
        "_type": "child",
        "_id": "some_is_2",
        "_score": 0,
       }
      ]
     }
    }
   }
  }]
 }
}

Comment: I've updated my answer and use `must` instead of `filter`

Comment: result is coming proper, but function_score is not changing _score value, so unable to sort

Comment: That's a different issue, this one is solved ;-) Feel free to create a new question with your specific problem.